# Создание таблицы, ошибка «отношение не существует»

Tags: postgresql

Запрос создания таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tasks (
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tasks_id_seq'::regclass)
, title character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL
, priority integer NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT tasks_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Выходит ошибка:

> `error: отношение "tasks_id_seq" не существует`

Что делать? Как решить? Работаю через `pg`, `Node.JS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE "tasks_id_seq";
```

А
[лучше](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial)
(для *PSQL 10+*):

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tasks (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
, title TEXT NOT NULL
, priority INTEGER NOT NULL
)
;
```

Comment: спасибо БОЛЬШОЕ, очень помогли.